# How to configure own REST consumer library

Tags: java, json, rest, groovy, jackson

we have a REST API in our company and I want to write a Groovy library so other groovy projects can use that library to easily access the REST API.

Library calls should be like this (`http://[static_url]/rest/api/project/123`):

```
def manager = new ProjectManager()
def project = manager.get(123)
```

Behind the scene:

```
def client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
def webTarget = client.target(uri.build("/project/$pid"))
def project = webTarget.request().get(Project.class)
return project
```

But I don't know **how to configure** my library f.e. to handle common problems with Jackson/JSON such as **date format conversion**.

```
Caused by:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException:
Can not construct instance of java.util.Date
from String value '2016-02-22 11:09:12'
```

With Spring Framework loading application.yml I could just add:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

But due to the fact I'm coding a library there is no bootstrapping where to configure those things or loading a configuration?! I'm pretty new to Java/Groovy world.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign and http://square.github.io/retrofit/ both of which seem to do what you are trying to write?

Comment: Actually no, thank you for those links. I definitly dont want to reinvent things, if there is already a library doing those things for me I'd appreciate that. I will have a look at them.

Comment: @tim_yates Fun fact: I have same issue when using the Retrofit2 library using the Gson converter: `java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2016-02-22 11:08:27']: Invalid time zone indicator ' ' at com.google.gson [...]`